# failed: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "users_userprofile" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, migration

Using django 10 and postgres 9.4.

After the website full setup I noticed that I cannot create new objects from my applications, default django apps like users are OK.

ran makemigrations and migrate afterwords, and when re trying it says nothing to migrate.
To make it simple:
When entering django shell and typing

```
from users.models import *
User.objects.all()
Out[3]: [<User: root>]
```

but :

```
UserProfile.objects.all()
Out[4]:
<repr(<django.db.models.query.QuerySet at 0x39b4610>) failed: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "users_userprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: ...."is_superuser", "users_userprofile"."wight" FROM "users_use...
                                                             ^
```

UserProfile is my  site users with onetoone to django.contrib.auth

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you run `makemigrations <yourappname>`?

Comment: that did the trick :) thanks, thought i did it earlier

Answer (score -3):

you must import the django.setup before doing the operation:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

Comment: out of context.